# JAXB write and read byte[] to xml - different values

Tags: java, jaxb, byte

I try to transform a string into an array of byte (byte[]) and save it in a xml file.
my problems are different values of the byte[] after marshal und unmarshal the object with jaxb.

I´m sorry for the format of my posting!

`

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Token {

private byte[] token;    

public void createToken(){
 String stringTest = "ABCDEF";
  this.token = stringTest.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
 }


public byte[] getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(byte[] token) {
    this.token = token;
}
}// ENDE CLASS TOKEN



 @XmlRootElement(namespace = "TokenNS")
 public class TokenCollection {


 private List<byte[]> collection = new ArrayList<>();



public void addToken(byte[] tokenIn){
    this.collection.add(tokenIn);
}



 @XmlElement( name = "TokenCollection")
public List<byte[]> getTokenCollection(){
    return this.collection;
}

public void test(){
    Token t = new Token();
    t.createToken();
    byte[] tmp = t.getToken();
    this.addToken(tmp);
}



 }// ENDE TOKENCOLLECTION






      STARTER:

      public Starter() {

      Path path = Paths.get("trivial.xml");

      tc.test();




      JAXB.marshal(tc, System.out);
      try (Writer out = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        JAXB.marshal(tc, out);
    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

`

OUTPUT:
        Should be:
                65 66 67 68 69 70

XML-FILE (with wrong values): 

       `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
       <ns2:tokenCollection xmlns:ns2="TokenNS">
            <TokenCollection>QUJDREVG</TokenCollection>
       </ns2:tokenCollection>`

Comment: Can you post the result XML file?

Comment: Result is in the "token" tag (notepad++):

`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:tokenCollection xmlns:ns2="TokenNS">
    <TokenCollection>
        <token>QUJDREVG</token>
        <tokenWidth>6</tokenWidth>
    </TokenCollection>
</ns2:tokenCollection>
`

Comment: And what is the type of `token`? Can you also post the `TokenCollection` class?

Answer (score 4):

A JAXB (JSR-222) implementation will represent `byte[]` in XML as the `base64Binary` schema type.  If you want an alternate representation you can use an `XmlAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Now after you edited your post, it works perfectly.

I read the XML with the following code, and in the end it prints the same `"ABCDEF"` string:

```
Path path = Paths.get("trivial.xml");
TokenCollection tc = JAXB.unmarshal(path.toFile(), TokenCollection.class);

// Prints "ABCDEF"
System.out.println(new String(tc.getTokenCollection().get(0),
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: we suppose that JAXB converts the values (which are between -128 and 127) somehow in the marshal-process. maybe the xml-file is written by JAXB in a different charset or something in this direction and i can´t get the correct, the original value.

Comment: No, JAXB handles byte arrays well. Byte arrays are represented as Base64 strings in the XML.

Comment: yesterday we tested the algorithms without problems unless i write and read the xml file. the values in the byte array i write into the file are produced by this codefragment:  
`        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
         this.setToken(new byte[this.getTokenWidth()]);
         random.nextBytes(getToken()); 
`

Comment: from a different point of view: i only need the code to store a byte array with random values in a xml file and restore the values. the token class object is more or less only a simple byte array with a given length. the tokencollection has a list of tokens and the tokenCollection is that what i try to persist in a xml file. but it seems the marshaler  alters the values in the array because the simple values "ABCDEF.." (dec:65,66,67..n) aren´t readable in the file ..

Comment: The problem is the object itself alters the byte array. It is ok to fill it with random values, but do it outside the class.

Comment: i´m not sure if i got your idea.

TOKEN:
@XmlRootElement
public class Token {


private byte[] token;    



public void createToken(){
    String stringTest = "ABCDEF";
    this.token = stringTest.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}// ENDE createToken
    

public byte[] getToken() {
        return token;
    }


 public void setToken(byte[] token) {
        this.token = token;
    }


}// ENDE CLASS TOKEN

Comment: TOKENCOLLECTION:
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "TokenNS")
public class TokenCollection {
    
   
    private List<byte[]> collection = new ArrayList<>();
   
   
    
    public void addToken(byte[] tokenIn){
        this.collection.add(tokenIn);
    }
    
    
    
     @XmlElement( name = "TokenCollection")
    public List<byte[]> getTokenCollection(){
        return this.collection;
    }
    
    public void test(){
        Token t = new Token();
        t.createToken();
        byte[] tmp = t.getToken();
        this.addToken(tmp);
    }
}// ENDE TOKENCOLLECTION

Comment: STARTER:
public Starter() {
        initComponents();
       
        
         Path path = Paths.get("trivial.xml");
         
   
         tc.test();
      
         
     
          
        JAXB.marshal(tc, System.out);
        try (Writer out = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
            JAXB.marshal(tc, out);
        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    
         
    }

Comment: OUTPUT: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:tokenCollection xmlns:ns2="TokenNS">
    <TokenCollection>QUJDREVG</TokenCollection>
</ns2:tokenCollection>

the same error again ..

Comment: in the last 4 comments i have reduced the problem to the core. 
the classes are now only a few lines long.
where (which class) do you think should i manipulate the byte[] and where should i marshal?

Comment: Edit your question, don't expect me to process the code from your comments. Also delete unneccessary comments as this is becoming nonsense.

Comment: Bocsánat, yes you´re right, i´m sorry for the circumstances, i edited the original post

Comment: Semmi baj. Now after your edit, your code works. See my edited answer how to read it.

Comment: well :-) thank you! it works. i´m too inexperienced to face the problem which was in the unmarshal method? i see the difference between our unmarshal code fragments, but i don´t understand why my way doesn´t work :-) anyway thank you for your help and your endurance!

Comment: I think that the problem was - again - that your `Token` class modified the byte array inside the `setTokenWidth()` method which should not be there.